# angular ready function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two controllers with same data depending upon language selection controller will load.When an item is clicked on the list item is loading but the problem is when other items are clicked angular ready function is not working and am seeing previously loaded item only

```
   .controller('EnCtrl', function($scope,sharedCartService) {
var cart = sharedCartService.cart;       
 $scope.menu_items=[
            {"p_id":"1",
             "p_name":"coffe ",
             "p_image_id":"coffe",
             "p_price":"50"
            },
            {"p_id":"2",
             "p_name":"Tea",
             "p_image_id":"Tea",
             "p_price":"50"
            },
            {"p_id":"3",
             "p_name":"Masala",
             "p_image_id":"Masala",
             "p_price":"50"
            }];


            $scope.showProductInfo=function (id,img,name,price) {    
             sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_id', id);
             sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_img', img);
             sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_name', name);
             sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_price', price);
             window.location.href = "#";
         };


         $scope.addToCart=function(id,image,name,price){  
              cart.add(id,image,name,price,1);  
         };  
    })
```

Kctrl

```
.controller('kCtrl', function($scope,sharedCartService) {
var cart = sharedCartService.cart;

   $scope.menu_items=[
        { "p_id": "1",
         "p_name": "ಕಾಫಿ",
          "p_image_id": "coffe",
         "p_price": "50"
        },
        { "p_id": "2", 
          "p_name": "ಚಹಾ",
           "p_image_id": "Tea",
         "p_price": "50"
        },
        { "p_id": "3",
         "p_name": "ಮಸಾಲಾ",
        "p_image_id": "Masala",
         "p_price": "50"
        }];     

        $scope.showProductInfo=function (id,img,name,price) {   
         sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_id', id);
         sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_img', img);
         sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_name', name);
         sessionStorage.setItem('product_info_price', price);
         window.location.href = "#";
     };


     $scope.addToCart=function(id,image,name,price){  
          cart.add(id,image,name,price,1);  
     };  
})
```

Product Controller

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope) {
//onload event
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.id= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_id');
        $scope.img= "img/"+ sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_img')+".jpg";
        $scope.name= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_name');
        $scope.price= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_price');
    });
```

En.html

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="item in menu_items"  >
            <h2  ng-click="showProductInfo(item.p_id,item.p_image_id,item.p_name,item.p_price)" > {{item.p_name}} </h2>
   <p   ng-click="showProductInfo(item.p_id,item.p_image_id,item.p_name,item.p_price)">{{item.p_price}}</p>
        </ion-list>
```

Productpage.html

```
<div>
                <p> {{name}}</p>
                <p>{{price}}</p>
                </div>
```

Updated after comments.When an item is clicked dataupdate message is displayed.Item information is not getting

.

```
controller('EnCtrl', function($scope,sharedCartService,$rootScope) {
var cart = sharedCartService.cart;       
 $scope.menu_items=[
            {"p_id":"1",
             "p_name":"coffe ",
             "p_image_id":"coffe",
             "p_price":"50"
            },
            {"p_id":"2",
             "p_name":"Tea",
             "p_image_id":"Tea",
             "p_price":"50"
            },
            {"p_id":"3",
             "p_name":"Masala",
             "p_image_id":"Masala",
             "p_price":"50"
            }];


            $scope.showProductInfo=function (id,img,name,price) {   
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataUpdate', {id: id,img: img,name: name,price: price})
             window.location.href = "#";
         };


         $scope.addToCart=function(id,image,name,price){  
              cart.add(id,image,name,price,1);  
         };  
    })
```

Product Controller

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on('dataUpdate', function(data) {
         $scope.id = data.id;
          $scope.img = data.img;
         $scope.name = data.name;
         $scope.price=data.price;
})
})
```

Plunker demo
https://plnkr.co/edit/zhvBzOzDtgOiTEGjBqAp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Actually `.ready` method is not Angular function but jqLite method (or jQuery method if you included it on your page; by default angular uses jqLite but if you include jQuery it will be used instead). `angular.element(document)` returns an element wrapped in jqLite object and `ready` is method of this object. Back to your main problem: 'ready' method callback is called only once when DOM is fully loaded, it's not called again until next page reload. Please check docs of [`ready` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

You can broadcast an event with your data on $rootScope in click handler and then access this data in another controller in the event listener.
So in you click handler do this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('dataUpdate', {id: id, name: name, img: img, price: price})
```

And in product controller add this (use event data to updated controller $scope):

```
 $rootScope.$on('dataUpdate', function(data) {
         $scope.id = data.id;
         $scope.img = data.img;
         $scope.name = data.name;
         ...
 });
```

*Update after comments questions*

You have to inject `$rootScope` into each controller in which you want to use it:

```
.controller('EnCtrl', function($scope,sharedCartService, $rootScope) {
...
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
```

## Answer update

I've noticed that you redirect in your click handler. So please try just removing `ready` handler so that your controller reads localStorage every time it's initialised:

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.id= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_id');
        $scope.img= "img/"+ sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_img')+".jpg";
        $scope.name= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_name');
        $scope.price= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_price');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any other examples for this like on ng-click I should get that item related information

Comment: No there is no parent-child relationship in controllers

Comment: Ok, please see updated answer. Described solution will work no matter what relation between controllers is

Comment: I tried it getting TypeError for $broadcast TypeError: Cannot read property '$broadcast' of undefined

Comment: You have to inject  $rootScope into your controllers to use it

Comment: .controller('EnCtrl', function($scope,sharedCartService) {    $scope.showProductInfo=function(id,desc,img,name,price,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast                                                           ('dataUpdate', {id: id, img: img, name: name,price: price});                                                        window.location.href = "#/page";
        }      })

Comment: It's not working when item is clicked dataUpdate message is displayed

Comment: Next update. I hope it will work now but if not please provide working jsFiddle with your example

Comment: I have created a plunker example please check it

Answer (score 1):

@user3698911, in addition to @Bartek Fryzowicz's answer,

You may also want to look at:

[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Note from angular:

> (deprecated, use angular.element(callback) instead of
>   angular.element(document).ready(callback))